# Entering into multiple directories in Unix and deleting a particular file

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, shell-script

I have a list of directories that I want to go into and delete particular files.
For example, the directory names I have are as below:

```
091513
090213
082612
071611
020908
011009
...
062308
```

Each of these directories has 4 files in them and the file names are:

```
dealer_score_01.txt
dealer_score_02.txt
dealer_score_03.txt
dealer_score_04.txt
```

I want to write a script that would go into each of these directories and delete:

```
dealer_score_01.txt
dealer_score_03.txt
```

Can someone please help me with that?

Comment: `man find`, read the `exec` and `name` parts

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go into each directory separately. Just pass the file names you want deleted to `find` and delete them with the `-delete` option.

```
find . -type f \
\( -name 'dealer_score_01.txt' -or -name 'dealer_score_03.txt' \) -delete
```

Leave out `-delete` to make sure you delete the right files.

Comment: Hi Slhck, Thanks for the reply. I want to delete these files only in certain directories.If i use the command above, it would delete these files in all the directories. Is there any way to delete only in few directories by specifying the directory names in which i want these files to be deleted?

Comment: You can just specify the directory names instead of `.` for the `find` command. For example `find 091513 090213 -type f …`

Comment: How many directories can I specify at a time in the find command? I have more than 200 directories that I want to do this with...

Comment: You can specify as many as you want. How do you get the list of directories in the first place? In a text file? From a command? Maybe you should clarify your question and tell us what *exactly* you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the directories already (as your comments suggest) you could do it with a loop.  If the list of directories is, say, in `dir_list`, and assuming none of your directories contain new lines in their name:

```
while read -r dir; do
  rm -f "$dir"/dealer_score_0{1,3}.txt
done < dir_list
```